# For every periodic continuous function $f$, the function $s\to \int_a^b f(x/s)\, dx $ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Fix $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$, and define a function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by
> $$g(s)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x/s)\, dx \quad & \text{if }s\ne0 \\ \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx \quad & \text{if } s=0\end{cases}$$
> Show that $g$ is continuous.

#### Remarks

Continuity at the points $s\ne 0$ is not difficult: as $t\to s$, we have $f(x/t)\to f(x/s)$ uniformly with respect to $x\in [a,b]$, so the integrals converge:
$$\int_a^b f(x/t)\, dx \to \int_a^b f(x/s)\, dx $$
However, this approach breaks down at $s=0$. How to proceed in this case?

Comment: This seems to be a nice, reasonably challenging question.  Yes, he did not show work; but half the questions here do not show work and are less interesting than this one.

Comment: @MarkFischler Feel free to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

The properties of continuous functions immediately show that $g(s)$ is continuous at all points other than $s = 0$, since neither integration over a fixed finite interval, nor scaling the mapped variable by dividing by a non-zero real can turn a continuous function into a discontinuous one.  So the meaty problem is to show that
$$
\lim_{s = 0} \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x/s) dx = \int_0^1f(x)dx
$$
Let's write $b = a + ns + q$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $0 \leq q < s$, and re-write the left hand side (by splitting up the integral) as 
$$
\lim_{s = 0} \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x/s) dx = 
\frac{1}{b-a} \lim_{s = 0}  \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{a+ks}^{a+(k+1)s} f(x/s) dx 
+ \int_{a+ns}^{a+ns+q} f(x/s) dx
\right]
$$
Let's deal with that sum first, changing variables to $u = x/s - k$, then  splitting each integral into two ranges, applying the $f(x) = f(x+1)$ property, and re-combining:
$$
\int_{a+ks}^{a+(k+1)s} f(x/s) dx  = s \int_{u=a/s}^{a/s+1} 
 f(u) du  
$$
$$
s \int_{u=a/s}^{1+a/s+1}  f(u) du  
= s \int_{a/s}^{\lceil a/s \rceil }  f(u) du + s \int_{\lceil a/s \rceil }^{1+a/s}  f(u) du
$$
where the notation $\lceil a/s \rceil$ means the smallest integer not less than $a/s$.

Now  we use $f(x) = f(x+1)$ to get
$$ s \int_{\lceil a/s \rceil }^{1+a/s}  f(u) du = 
s \int_{\lceil a/s \rceil -1}^{a/s}  f(u) du  
$$
and place that integral first to re-combine to :
$$
s \int_{\lceil a/s \rceil -1}^{\lceil a/s \rceil }  f(u) du  =  s \int_0^1 f(u) du
$$
So the full sum is (swithing back to use $x$ as our dummy variable)
$$
\frac{1}{b-a} \lim_{s = 0}  s \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^1 f(x) dx = \frac{1}{b-a} \lim_{s = 0}  ns \int_0^1 f(x) dx 
$$
But since $ns = (b-a) + q$ for some $0 \leq q < s$ this is 
$$ \frac{1}{b-a} \lim_{s = 0}  \int_0^1 f(x) dx + \frac{q}{b-a}\int_0^1 f(x) dx 
$$
and in the first part, the $s$ has disappeared so the limit is trivial, while the second part can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $s$ small compared to $b-a$.  So the sum part gives 
$$ \frac{1}{b-a} \lim_{s = 0}  \int_0^1 f(x) dx 
$$
and all that remains to be shown is that 
$$
\lim_{s = 0}  
\int_{a+ns}^{a+ns+q} f(x/s) dx = 0
$$
Here, let $u = x/s -n$ to transform to
$$
\lim_{s = 0}  
s \int_{a/s}^{a/s+q} f(u) du = 0
$$
Here we hit a snag:  the integral is over some part of the unit interval, but I know of no theorem that says that the integral of a continuous function is bounded.  However, if $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous then its integral over a finite interval is bounded, and so this limit is indeed zero.